# Is there maximum number of images that can be cached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have 700 frames/images of 352x288 size 9kbs on my server.  I want to render them like a video clip on a browser. I am using JQueryAjax to get these images and return an array of `<img>`'s to be loaded one after another via a timer. I have found when i try to cache all 700 images I get an unspecified server error.  I have reduced the cache to 250 images which work. My question is whether there is a limit to a cache of this type and is it dependent upon browser, image size?

I ask this because to get round my 250 max problem I was going to update the cache dynamically as soon as the image has been displayed.  But this could fall down if it is dependent on things like PC/client browser limitations.

thanks.

my existing code:

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="Play Motion Clip from Beginning">
<img alt="Play Motion" src="../Images/play_green_controls.png" style="border-style: none; width: 32px; height: 32px; background-color: #000000; cursor: pointer;"
            id="btnPlay" />
</a>
<div id="divImage" >
hello andy
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cache = [];
    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
    var interval = 100;
    var _total = 0;

    $("#btnPlay").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default3.aspx/GetClips",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                cache = [];
                 _total = 0;
                $.each(msg.d, function () {
                    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
                    cacheImage.src = this['Text'];
                    cache[_total] = cacheImage;
                    _total++;
                }
                );
                setInterval('swapImages()', interval);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
    var div = document.getElementById('divImage');
    var _index = 0;
    function swapImages() {

        if (_index < _total) {              
            if (_index > 0) {
                div.removeChild(cache[_index - 1]);
            }               
            div.appendChild(cache[_index]);
        }
        else {
            interval = 0;
        }
        _index++;
        if (_index  == _total)
        {
            div.removeChild(cache[_index - 1]);
            _index = 0;
            div.appendChild(cache[_index]);
        }
    }
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static ArrayList GetClips()
{
    ArrayList _arr = new ArrayList();
    int _max = 250;  //seems to be safe
    string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Cloud\Catalogues\000EC902F17F\2\2013\10\6\10\f1fe61da-4684-48ed-a503-4a5586ece9c8","*.jpg"); //731
       for (int _index = 0; _index < _files.Length; _index++)
    {
        string _file = _files[_index];
        string[] _bits = _file.Split('\\');
        string _url = "Portal/Catalogues/000EC902F17F/2/2013/10/6/10/f1fe61da-4684-48ed-a503-4a5586ece9c8/" + _bits[10];
        ListItem _item = new ListItem();
        _item.Text = _url;
        _arr.Add(_item);
        if (_index == _max - 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return _arr;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, you're not really prefetching the actual image data; you're just fetching the URLs. The browser will still have to issue a separate HTTP request to fetch the actual image bits for each one.

Comment: @Pointy Hi, thanks for your reply.  I thought I was caching as in my jquery I have this:    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
                    cacheImage.src = this['Text'];
                    cache[_total] = cacheImage;

Comment: where cache[_total] is holding the image control...

Comment: Well, yes, I guess I meant that there are still lots and lots of separate HTTP transactions for the images. I can't say I have any clue as to how or why you're getting those errors, but I really doubt it's a client-side problem.  For small images like that, a "fat" client (computer, as opposed to a phone) should be able to cache hundreds easily.

Comment: @Pointy Hi,I would have thought that too.  Also,I just run the code on IE9 and I was getting flicker so I am now a bit stuck on 2 things.  I did try sprites but the memory just jumped and never went down so I cannot use that .. :(